# Drawing line using transmition with kineticjs

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I would like to drawLine with kineticJS and then use transmition.

```
line = new Kinetic.Line({
    points: [0, 0, 50, 50],
    stroke: "red"
});
```

The problem is that I cannot use transmition for points.

Any workaround? Like drawing polygon which looks like line?

Answer (score 1):

There is no current workaround or great way to do this, but you essentially would have to stop the animation, modify the points, then start the animation again.

```
//Pseudo-code:
  trans = line.transitionTo({
    // configuration being transitioned
  });

  trans.stop();
  //add points or change points.
  trans.start();
```